# What's the right HTML tag for a subnav item that doesn't link to anything?

Tags: html, navigation, accessibility

I'm thinking about a navigation menu where some item are just label for the subnav. For example:

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/subitem1.html">Subitem 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/subitem2.html">Subitem 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="/subitem3.html">Subitem 3</a></li>
        </ul>
       </ul>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
```

In this case "Item 1" is just a trigger that, on `hover`, shows the `subnav` list, but it actually does not link to any page. I see this kind of structure very often (usually with `e.preventDefault()` applied to `click` event).

Is it right to use an anchor tag here? Or would it be more correct  to use another tag, like, for example, a span tag? Or something else?

An anchor tag can be focused pressing tab key, but it actually wouldn't link to a page. On the other side, a span tag is not focused on tab key, so it doesn't give context to subnav anchors.

Comment: this can be anything, if you don't want to redirect, use `<a>Item 1</a>` so that's without the href, or you could use a `<p>` element, or even an image, etc

Comment: use a `span` tag - it has the same initial properties as an anchor so adding the class to your span (if your anchor has a class for styling) will apply the same styles as the anchor has without the need for any overriding styles (apart from cursor: pointer if you want to keep the hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that "#" is not a valid URL: https://www.webaccessibility.com/best_practices.php?best_practice_id=946

But you can perfectly use an anchor to the submenu as it reflects your navigation

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#subnav1">Item 1</a>
    <ul id="subnav1" tabindex="-1">
      <li><a href="/subitem1.html">Subitem 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/subitem2.html">Subitem 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/subitem3.html">Subitem 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

EDIT: As pointed out by a comment, the `tabindex=-1` attribute should be set on an `ul` element in order to be keyboard accessible.

Comment: That sounds as the most reasonable answer to me. But probably you meant href=#subnav1, right?

Comment: @AndreaVerde Yes. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: I suggest you test that with keyboard focus. Also with a screen reader.

Comment: @aardrian, oh no, i won't test it, it would not work ;-) you're right.

Comment: So @aardrian, what do you suggest?

Comment: I would just make the link into a proper link. Make an index page that contains a list of the same items in the navigation bar. You can even preface it with a paragraph of content. This means no wacky rejiggering of the menu code, it is still accessible, you get an opportunity for some SEO (ugh), and your navigation and site structure match. In my own user testing over ~20 years, this is more effective than non-existing pages listed in navigation with wacky JS/HTML to _almost_ make them work.

Answer (score 0):

Its good practice to follow uniform html structure as you have posted in the question. In case "Item 1" is not a link, you can use `tabindex=-1` attr anchor tag to avoid focus on the tab button press.

```
<a class="yourclassname" href="#" tabindex=-1 rel="nofollow">Item 1</a>
```

In javascript, you can have this small piece of code to avoid hash from appearing in the browser address bar.

```
addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('yourclassname')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this - I'd say having the markup match the semantics of the content is much more important than having it be uniform.

Comment: Yes, that's my doubt. Using an anchor, that actually doesn't work as an anchor, isn't it semantically wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in your situation, using a `<button>` element provides the best semantics and keyboard navigation.

However, after a lot of experimentation, I've concluded that the best screen reader support comes from the types of structures shown by the Open Ajax folks and Terril Thompson. Their examples get the best speech feedback from ARIA. 
You will notice that they do not use `<a>` or `<button>` to toggle the subnav list. See [Terrell's sample](http://staff.washington.edu/tft/tests/menus/html5/index.html).

Notice the “About” `<li>`:

```
<ul id="nav" class="menubar root-level" role="menubar">
   <li class="menu-parent" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" title="About Menu">
      About
        <ul id="about" role="menu" class="menu" aria-hidden="true">
           <li role="menuitem" class="menu-item" tabindex="-1">
// etc. //
```

The `<li>` is made focusable and clickable with the tabindex attribute and JavaScript event listeners.

The advantage that I see is that the ARIA works best when the focus is on an element that is the parent of the sublist.

Comment: The URL seems to be missing.

Comment: @JeffG01 could you please give the link to the sample you are talking about?